# how can i replicate servletcontext object in distributed environment

Tags: java, tomcat, distributed

I have two Tomcat servlets, like these bellow:

Tomcat 1

```
    ServletContext application1=getServletConfig().getServletContext();
    application.setAttribute("message","hello World");
```

Tomcat 2

```
    ServletContext application2 = getServletConfig().getServletContext();
    application.getAttribute("message");

    Current output  : null 
    Expected output : "hello World"
```

and I want the result to be something like what I've explained above. Please suggest me any useful thing from where I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

A `servlet context` contains attributes common to a single web application instance. If you want that some data will be common to different instances, you'd better store them in a database. If you want memory only data (not persistent), you can also use distributed maps  like `hazelcast`.

Comment: hazelcast is distributed concept but have performance issues so i want to implement some of there feature not all

Comment: You must have high performances requirements if hazelcast is not enough, because it can be configured as a memory only solution (neither disk, nor database), but you might also look at HSQL or H2 that can be used as memory only databases.

Comment: @SergeBallesta: i have also same problem and i dont want any database connection. i need quick response,i know hazlcast use some serialization concept can i achive same thing using serilization without using hazelcast